# How to overlay image with information?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I can't find tutorial which shows how make image with information on it using html and css. Can you assist?

Example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fall.lt](http://up.fall.lt/failai/jpg/2ca74ae66611e4e5e018c9278d03b7d1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask here. We like to see code showing your own efforts

Comment: @mplungjan ok, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src=""/> //path to your img.
    <div class="information">blah blah</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
   position:relative;
}

.information {
   position:absolute;
   top:  //position your information
   left: //position your information

   //other styling for your information
}
```

The idea is to simply use `position:absolute` to position your additional information (texts, other images,...) on top of your image.

Another option is to use an editor like photoshop to modify your image with additional information.

Comment: I will do it soon, because now i get an error witch makes me wait

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a wrapping div as a container for absolute positioning.

We can wrap both an img and an text element inside a wrapper div.

```
<div class="image">

      <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="" />

      <h2>Text Over Image</h2>

</div>
```

The we set the necessary positioning properties.

```
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%;  /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

[View this code in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQadwR)

Comment: your code didn't work

Comment: You can check the attached link for a live example on codepen, it seems to be working just fine :)